# PyMathProg read CPLEX lp file

Tags: cplex, glpk

Is it possible to read an lp file in PyMathProg? Since it uses GLPK I wonder if this might be possible.

Comment: No answer for you, but imho this one looks rather deprecated / unmaintained. While i have thought that i did evaluate all python-based math-opt tools existing, this one never crossed my path (probably for a reason).

Comment: Ok, thank you. So I look for another solution.

Comment: Those tools are not all equal and different people prefer different ones depending on some side-constraints. So don't take this as a "use this in any case" recommendation, but [Python-MIP](https://docs.python-mip.com/en/latest/quickstart.html#saving-loading-and-checking-model-properties) is less old, can be installed through pip on all common platforms and (as the link shows) should fulfil your task. It's also somewhat similar in regards to modelling (not matrix-form like). (It's not based on GLPK, but Cbc which is considerer superior by some people incl. me)

Comment: Currently I'm using GLPK via command line. We prefer to generate lp files, even this is not  really efficient. But it helps to get a human readable problem file to check for erros or consistency and we can handle this over to CPLEX for more difficult problems. Even with glpk in C I generated lp files (I'm a rather old styl user). I will check out Python-MIP.